# Firebase listener returning all children when i only want a specific child

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This is my database structure:

[image: 1]

Here is my code:

```
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getTasks(dataSnapshot);
            mTasksRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
.
.
.

//populate recyclerview with data from firebase
private void getTasks(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        mTasks.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(Task.class));
    }
    Collections.sort(mTasks);
    mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks, getContext());
    mTasksRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The problem is this code retrieves everything in the database, tasks and users and is adding user objects to my Task arraylist somehow, and causing blank items to show up in my recyclerview.  What code can I use to only retrieve items in the Tasks section of my database?

I know that this is happening because datasnapshot.getChildren is returning everything in the database.  I thought using datasnapshot.child("Tasks") would work, but it did not.

Comment: Can you post the path for your database reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datasnapshot.child("Tasks")
```

will not work, you need to refer to the Tasks table in a database reference and then add the childEventListener to it. Try this instead.

```
DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("Tasks");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        getTasks(dataSnapshot);
        mTasksRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The key is setting the path in your data reference. You need to do:

```
DatabaseReference db = mDatabase.child("Tasks").child("YourTask");
   db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded...
   @Override
   public void onChildRemoved...
   @Override
   public void onChildUpdated...
```